# Log shipping for few tables in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

Is it possible to log shipping for few tables only in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SImple answer: NO. THere is no per table log. THere is ONE log per database. SImple like that.
You want partial table stuff - only chance is replication.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure this using FileGroups (ie. put tables into a different FILEGROUP), and manually manage the restore process.

Initially only restoring the tables you require
Lookup Partial Restore.

This is a currently working.